# Add letter to numbering of theorem environments. Locally, and then restore to default behaviour?

Tags: numbering, environments, theorems, thmtools

I am trying to locally modify the numbering of theorem environments. The basic idea is to have Theorem 1, then Theorem 2A, Lemma 2B, Lemma 2C, then back to Theorem 3, Lemma 4 etc. The output of the MWE explains this more accurately and more concisely:

[image: Example of output]

- ***How*** should this be achieved? Ideally, the solution will also work with the packages listed in MWE, uncommented.

---

***MWE***

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem, theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{myTheorem} %defining myTheorem
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,refname={lemma, lemmas},Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},sibling=myTheorem]{myLemma} %defining myLemma
\declaretheorem[name=Sentence,refname={sentence,sentences},Refname={Sentence,Sentences},sibling=myTheorem] {mySentence} %defining mySentence

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
This is an example part of a large document.
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

Some statements, normal behaviour.
\begin{myTheorem}
    This numbering is OK.
\end{myTheorem}
\begin{mySentence}
    This numbering is OK.
\end{mySentence}

Now three similar statements. How to make local change in numbering for the following three instances of different environments?
\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.3a.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.3b.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{mySentence}
    This should be 1.3c.
\end{mySentence}

Again different statements. Back to normal behaviour.
\begin{myTheorem}
    This should be 1.4.
\end{myTheorem}

\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.5.
\end{myLemma}

\end{document}
```

---

The closest solution I found along these lines is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47954/116907) by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) to the question [*Numbering a theorem with a letter but not changing numbering of other theorems*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47951/116907). Changing that answer naively didn't work, however. It had no effect, maybe because one of the packages changes counter names.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:

- Copy the definition of `subequations` from `amsmath`
- ... but taking care to make sure you modify `\the<counter>` for **each environment impacted** <sup>$</sup>

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem, theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{myTheorem} %defining myTheorem
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,refname={lemma, lemmas},Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},sibling=myTheorem]{myLemma} %defining myLemma
\declaretheorem[name=Sentence,refname={sentence,sentences},Refname={Sentence,Sentences},sibling=myTheorem] {mySentence} %defining mySentence

\makeatletter
\newcounter{myparentThm}
\newenvironment{mysubtheorems}{%
        \refstepcounter{myTheorem}
        \protected@edef\themyparentThm{\themyTheorem}%
        \setcounter{myparentThm}{\value{myTheorem}}%
        \setcounter{myTheorem}{0}%
        \def\themyTheorem{\themyparentThm\alph{myTheorem}}%
        \def\themyLemma{\themyparentThm\alph{myLemma}}%
        \def\themySentence{\themyparentThm\alph{mySentence}}%
        \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{myTheorem}{\value{myparentThm}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\chapter{Test Chapter}
This is an example part of a large document.
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

Some statements, normal behaviour.
\begin{myTheorem}
    This numbering is OK.
\end{myTheorem}
\begin{mySentence}
    This numbering is OK.
\end{mySentence}

\begin{mysubtheorems}
Now three similar statements. How to make local change in numbering for the following three instances of different environments?
\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.3a.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.3b.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{mySentence}\label{test:sentence}
    This should be 1.3c.
\end{mySentence}
\end{mysubtheorems}

Again different statements. Back to normal behaviour.
\begin{myTheorem}
    This should be 1.4.
\end{myTheorem}

\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.5.
\end{myLemma}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

---

<sup>$</sup> This is related to why the OP observed that [Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47954/116907) didn't work. In plain `amsthm`, when you define sibling counters, what you get is a theorem that uses the sibling counter directly. More precisely, when you call `\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}`, the code in `\begin{theorem}` would `\refstepcounter{equation}`, and when printing the theorem number it would call `\theequation`.

This is changed by `thmtools` (and I think `cleveref`), because cref-type commands work by mapping the counter name to its representation. In the case of `thmtools`, when you use a sibling counter using, e.g., the definition of `myLemma` in the code, you get

- A counter `myLemma` which has the same underlying count register as `myTheorem`,
- various supporting macros *including* `\themyLemma` which is set to equal to `\themyTheorem` via `\let`,
- and a `myLemma` environment which access its number using the counter `myLemma` and the format `\themyLemma`.

So to make things work with `thmtools`, you need

- code to swap out the counter values (which is basically the same as what Medina has in the linked answer, and also what `subequations` do)
- code to swap out, for each environment impacted, the corresponding `\the<env>` (since they were copied by `\let`, changing one doesn't change them all).

Note: I haven't fully tested compatibility with hyperref. If there are issues it would be solvable by changing the definitions of `\theH<env>` appropriately; see Appendix A.3.2 of `thmtools` manual.

Answer (score 0):

After staring at the thmtools code for a long time, I think I see a way to do this. The idea is to temporarily suspend the theorem counters in question (similar to thmtools' `continues` key), redefining `\the<theorem>` as we want. To do this for each theorem between the commands `\letteringtheorems` and `\stopletteringtheorems`, we use hooks. In particular, we use the kernel hooks, with a label, to add to the existing thmtools `preheadhook` because this allows us to later remove the added code with `\RemoveFromHook`. The thmtools commands `\addtotheorempreheadhook`, etc., have no such removal counterpart. Since we only want the number of the theorem that immediately follows `\letteringtheorems`, we use `\AddToHookNext` to store the number.

From some very basic tests, it seems to play nicely with `hyperref` and `\listoftheorems`. No promises it won't break other things, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter,style=plain,name=Theorem,refname={theorem, theorems},Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{myTheorem} %defining myTheorem
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,refname={lemma, lemmas},Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},sibling=myTheorem]{myLemma} %defining myLemma
\declaretheorem[name=Sentence,refname={sentence,sentences},Refname={Sentence,Sentences},sibling=myTheorem] {mySentence} %defining mySentence

\makeatletter
\newcounter{thmletter}
\newcommand{\letteringtheorems}{%
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/thmt@generic@preheadhook/before}{%
    \refstepcounter{\thmt@envname}%
    \xdef\tempcounterval{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
    }%
  \AddToHook{cmd/thmt@generic@preheadhook/after}[thmletters]{%
    \@xa\let\csname c@\thmt@envname\endcsname\c@thmt@dummyctr%
    \@xa\let\csname theH\thmt@envname\endcsname\theHthmt@dummyctr%
    \stepcounter{thmletter}%
    \@xa\def\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname{\tempcounterval\alph{thmletter}}%
    }%
  }
\newcommand{\stopletteringtheorems}{%
  \RemoveFromHook{cmd/thmt@generic@preheadhook/after}[thmletters]%
  \setcounter{thmletter}{0}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
This is an example part of a large document.
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

Some statements, normal behaviour.
\begin{myTheorem}
    This numbering is OK.
\end{myTheorem}
\begin{mySentence}
    This numbering is OK.
\end{mySentence}

Now three similar statements. How to make local change in numbering for the following three instances of different environments?

\letteringtheorems

\begin{myLemma}[label=abc]
    This should be 1.3a.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}[label=bla]
    This should be 1.3b.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{mySentence}
    This should be 1.3c.
\end{mySentence}

\stopletteringtheorems

Again different statements. Back to normal behaviour.
\begin{myTheorem}
    This should be 1.4.
\end{myTheorem}

\begin{myLemma}[label=hfd]
    This should be 1.5.
\end{myLemma}

\begin{myLemma}
    This should be 1.6.
\end{myLemma}

\listoftheorems

\end{document}
```

[image: thms]

[image: listofthms]